# MVVM Navigation Force Close Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I try using mvvm in my xamarin forms but i'm still litle bit confused with the navigation in each page, I Already Create Interface and NavigationService to handle all Navigation in my Xamarin Forms, there is no error code line but when i click the buton and try to navigate to other page it always crash. Here is some of my code 
My Interface

```
namespace KGVC.Interfaces
{
    public interface INavigationService
    {
        void NavigateToDashboard();
        void NavigateToLogout();
        void NavigateBack();
        void gotoNews();
        void goEvent();
        void gotoKGCash();
        void gotoCardCommnunity();
        void gotoSetting();
        void gotoNearbyLocation();
    }
}
```

my navigationservice

```
namespace KGVC.Services
{
    public class NavigationService : INavigationService
    {
        public  void goEvent()
        {
            var currentPage = GetCurrentPage();

             currentPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new EventPage());
        }

        public  void gotoCardCommnunity()
        {
            var currentPage = GetCurrentPage();

             currentPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new CardCommunityPage());
        }

        public  void gotoKGCash()
        {
            var currentPage = GetCurrentPage();

             currentPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new KGCashPage());
        }

        public  void gotoNearbyLocation()
        {
            var currentPage = GetCurrentPage();

             currentPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new StoreMaps());
        }

        public  void gotoNews()
        {
            var currentPage = GetCurrentPage();

             currentPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new RssFeedView());
        }

        public   void gotoSetting()
        {
            var currentPage = GetCurrentPage();

             currentPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new SettingPages());
        }

        public void NavigateBack()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public  void NavigateToDashboard()
        {

            var currentPage = GetCurrentPage();

             Application.Current.MainPage = new MainPage();
        }

        public void NavigateToLogout()
        {
            var currentPage = GetCurrentPage();
            Application.Current.MainPage = new NewPageLogin();
        }

        private Page GetCurrentPage()
        {
            var currentPage = Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.NavigationStack.LastOrDefault();

            return currentPage;
        }
    }
}
```

my view model

```
public class GridMenuViewModel
    {


        public ICommand gotoNews { get; private set; }
        public ICommand goEvent { get; private set; }
        public ICommand gotoKGCash { get; private set; }
        public ICommand gotoSetting { get; private set; }
        public ICommand gotoNearbyLocation { get; private set; }
        public GridMenuViewModel()
        {
            gotoNews = new Command(() =>
            {
                var navigationService = new NavigationService();

                navigationService.gotoNews();
            });
            goEvent = new Command(() =>
            {
                var navigationService = new NavigationService();

                navigationService.goEvent();
            });

            gotoKGCash = new Command(() =>
            {
                var navigationService = new NavigationService();

                navigationService.gotoKGCash();
            });
            gotoSetting = new Command(() =>
            {
                var navigationService = new NavigationService();

                navigationService.gotoSetting();
            });
            gotoNearbyLocation = new Command(() =>
            {
                var navigationService = new NavigationService();

                navigationService.gotoNearbyLocation();
            });
        }
    }
```

And my view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="True"
             NavigationPage.BackButtonTitle="False"
               BindingContext="{Binding GridMenuViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
             xmlns:control="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:KGVC.Views.MainPages"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="KGVC.Views.MainPages.GridMenu"
             Title="HOME"
            >


    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout >
            <StackLayout  BackgroundColor="##CEB053">
                <StackLayout  HeightRequest="35" BackgroundColor="##CEB053" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label  FontAttributes="Italic" TextColor="Black" Margin="9" Text="Hello," FontSize="15"/>
                    <Label  TextColor="Black"  Margin="9" Text="John Doe" FontSize="15" FontAttributes="Bold"/>

                </StackLayout>

                <StackLayout  Padding="0"  HeightRequest="30" BackgroundColor="#E3E6E3" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Margin="5" Source="ic_logo.png"/>
                    <Label  Text="Points" Margin="5" FontSize="13" TextColor="Black"/>
                </StackLayout>

            </StackLayout>


            <StackLayout  HeightRequest="220" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">

                <control:CarouselView HeightRequest="185" ItemsSource="{Binding MyDataSource}" Position="{Binding Position, Mode=TwoWay}">
                    <control:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Image  Source="{Binding Image}"/>

                        </DataTemplate>
                    </control:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                </control:CarouselView>
                <local:CarouselIndicators IndicatorHeight="9" IndicatorWidth="9" UnselectedIndicator="unselected_circle.png" SelectedIndicator="selected_circle.png" Position="{Binding Position}" ItemsSource="{Binding MyDataSource}" />
            </StackLayout>

            <ScrollView IsClippedToBounds="True" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" Orientation="Vertical" >

                    <Grid x:Name="controlGrid" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HeightRequest="370" Margin="15">

                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="0" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="100" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="100" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="100" />

                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <ColumnDefinition Width="110" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="110" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="110" />

                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" >
                            <Button Image="ic_account.png" Margin="5" 
        Style="{StaticResource plainButton}" />
                            <Label FontSize="12" Text="MY ACCOUNT" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                        </StackLayout>

                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
                        <Button Margin="5" Command="{Binding gotoCardCommunity}" Image="ic_card.png" 
        Style="{StaticResource plainButton}" />
                            <Label FontSize="12" Text="CARD" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                        </StackLayout>

                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2">
                        <Button Margin="5" Command="{Binding goEvent}" Image="ic_event" 
        Style="{StaticResource plainButton}" />
                            <Label FontSize="12" Text="PROMO" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                        </StackLayout>

                        <StackLayout Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Vertical">
                        <Button Margin="5" Command="{Binding gotoNearbyLocation}" Image="ic_store" 
        Style="{StaticResource plainButton}" />
                            <Label FontSize="12" Text="STORE LOCATIONS" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                        </StackLayout>

                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1">
                        <Button Margin="5" Command="{Binding gotoNews}"  Image="ic_news" 
        Style="{StaticResource plainButton}" />
                            <Label FontSize="12" Text="NEWS" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>

                        </StackLayout>


                        <StackLayout Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Orientation="Vertical">
                        <Button Margin="5"  Command="{Binding gotoKGCash}" Image="ic_kgcash" 
        Style="{StaticResource plainButton}" />
                            <Label FontSize="12" Text="E-WALLET" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                        </StackLayout>

                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0">
                            <Button Margin="5"  Image="ic_ecommerce" 
        Style="{StaticResource plainButton}" />
                            <Label FontSize="12" Text="E-COMMERCE" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                        </StackLayout>

                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1">
                        <Button Margin="5"  Command="{Binding gotoSetting}" Image="ic_pointsummary.png" 
        Style="{StaticResource plainButton}" />
                            <Label FontSize="12" Text="POINT SUMMARY" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                        </StackLayout>


                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2">
                        <Button Margin="5"  Command="{Binding gotoSetting}" Image="ic_setting" 
        Style="{StaticResource plainButton}" />
                            <Label FontSize="12" Text="SETTINGS" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                        </StackLayout>



                    </Grid>






            </ScrollView>



        </StackLayout>


    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

i already try change the navigation service to use pushmodalasync, make the navigation async but still crash, Anyone can help me ? and i'm not using prism , mvvmlight and other 3rd party mvvm nuget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your `MainPage`. Did you check if `GetCurrentPage()` actually returns something?

Try to change the `GetCurrentPage()` to:

```
Page GetCurrentPage() =>
  Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation?.NavigationStack?.LastOrDefault() ??
  Application.Current.MainPage;
```

Another problems that I spotted: 
1. [C# naming conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0(v=vs.71).aspx) are different from Java. Method names should start with a capital letter. Currently you have a pure mix. 
2. Initialising the `BindingContext` in XAML the way you did will create the `ViewModel` twice due to a [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42771108/xamarin-forms-viewmodellocator-get-called-twice). Change it to:

```
<ContentPage
  xmlns:vm="your-namespace.vm"
  ...>
  <ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <vm:GridMenuViewModel />
  </ContentPage.BindingContext>
</ContentPage>
```

3. No need to recreate the NavigationService for each command. Reuse it in your ViewModel. 
4. You have some corrupted XAML:

```
<StackLayout  BackgroundColor="##CEB053">
```

Fix the hex code. Generally speaking you could enable [XAMLC](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xamlc/) so you would get notified about XAML errors while building your code.

5. In order to use `PushAsync` your `MainPage` should be wrapped by `NavigationPage`. 
6. You need to await async code execution:

```
public async Task GoToCardCommnunity()
{
  var currentPage = GetCurrentPage();
  await currentPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new CardCommunityPage());
}
```

Check over the list above and pay attention to the application output and exceptions.

Comment: thaks for your answer its already work, using your GetCurrentPage method and change PushAsync to PushModalAsync and its work but it doesnt work when im try to use PushAsync Im using      Application.Current.MainPage = new MainPage(); in my main page it because after login i dont want my user can go back to login page again. Is that why i cant using push async ?

Comment: Updated my answer. Most probably it is due the fact that you are not awaiting asynchronous code execution. Also pay attention to suggestion #5.

Comment: i already change my code to make the main page in NavigationPage with this  Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage()); and it can execute pushasync but only once, after navigating to other page then go back to mainpage and navigating again to other page it will force close , this whole mvvm idea is still confused me, is mvvm mandatory to create enterprise application ?

Comment: What is the exception? Regarding MVVM check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653096/why-use-mvvm

Comment: the exception is "An unhandled exception occured." , i already tried to set breakpoint in the navigation service but its not going to break mode