# Multiple of the same view model are being created

Tags: xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin.Forms application, I have 1 page and am setting the view model in the xaml as such:

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <vm:MainViewModel />
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
```

The problem is, that when I put the app in the background and then open it again, I have 2 instances of `MainViewModel`. I can see with the debugger that a new one is created, but also code from the first one (before I put it in the background) is still being called (from event handlers).

How can I fix this? Is it possible to retain and use the same view model? Or am I forced to have a new one every time I close and reopen the app? If so, how do I make sure the old one is released from memory?

I'm running the app on an Android device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a regression bug, since it was reported/fixed multiple times.

I have a similar thread here on SO : [Xamarin.Forms ViewModelLocator get called twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42771108/xamarin-forms-viewmodellocator-get-called-twice)

Don't set the `BindingContext` in `XAML` unless it is a one page app, instead consider using an IoC container.